# Proving subsets with ab|x being a subset of a|x intersect b|x

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

(First time user on M.SE --- so open to feedback on my post, especially since I struggled to find a similar question)

Stuck on a proof for a class (having access only to Direct, Contrapositive, Contradiction type proofs), trying to prove:
If $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\{x \in \mathbb{Z} : ab \mid x\} \subseteq \{x \in \mathbb{Z} : a \mid x\} \cap \{x \in \mathbb{Z} : b|x\}$

So far I have deduced the following, but I'm stuck working forward and backward from here.  Am I using the wrong proof for this?  Or am I just missing the connection to prove this?

Proof:
Suppose y is in A, where A is the intersection.

Then $a \mid y$ and $b \mid y$.

Then $y = am$ and $y = bn$ for $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $am = bn$

I'm sure I'm missing something simple and have just fatigued myself from doing too many proofs today.

Comment: So you're stuck on how to prove that, if $ab|x,$ then $a|x$ and $b|x$? Is that your problem?

Comment: Break it down into parts. 1. If $ab|x,$ prove that $a|x.$ 2. If $ab|x,$ prove that $b|x.$ Can you do one of them?

Comment: ok, looking at the answer from sntx below, helped along with your questions @bof.  I've got the answer figured out now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ab|x$ then $x = (c)ab$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$, which can be written as $x = (ca)b$, i.e. $b|x$ but also $x = (cb)a$, i.e. $a|x$.

Comment: thanks, that was a very straight forward and helpful way of putting it.